# How to check if a file is being actively managed by chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a few files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` that I wish to clean up if they are not managed by chef (or no longer, i.e. were added by a recipe that is no longer in the node's run_list).

I would like to have some way to go over all the files in this directory at the end of each chef run, and delete those that didn't have a resource maintaining them (such as `apt_repository` or `template`), even if it was `(skipped due to action :nothing)` or `(up to date)`

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to manage the sources.d directory such that it doesn't include outdated repositories. There are many people managing the servers, mostly through chef. If someone for example added a recipe that adds a repository, and a year later someone else decides to remove that recipe, that repository will stay there until someone manually inspects the sources.d directory and removes it.

Comment: If you have control over the recipes, your best bet is to manage removing the unneeded sources at the end of the run using a delayed notification. Or write your own separate cleanup recipe that manges it and checks which resources/recipes were included

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the files and then let chef run. It will recreate everything that it "manages".

Comment: I thought about this, but I must be 100% sure that I will always be deleting the contents of the library before all the resources that manage it. Also, this may be an issue if another resource that requires one of the managed files (such as `apt_package`) will be called for when the directory is still empty

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and found a cookbook here that solves this problem: https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/managed_directory

Essentially, the cookbook is taking a list of everything in a specified directory and comparing it to the chef run_context, which has a list of all of the files that chef is directly managing. My problem was managing the files in a directory and making sure that only chef-managed files were kept. This managed_directory cookbook removes files that aren't managed by chef. If you want to just see the list of files managed, the relevant code you need is here:

```
managed_entries = run_context.root_run_context.resource_collection.all_resources.select do |r|
  r.identity.is_a?(String) && r.identity.start_with?("#{new_resource.path}/")
end.map(&:identity).uniq
```

Something along the lines of checking values inside the `run_context.root_run_context.resource_collection.all_resources` value should help out.